# how to remove the py/object when using jsonpickle to seriable object

Tags: python

now I am using `jsonpickle` to seriable object in Python 3, this is my code:

```
dingtalk_message_text = DingtalkMessageText("test")
        dingtalk_message_at = DingtalkMessageAt(True)
        dingtalk_message = DingtalkMessage('text', dingtalk_message_text, dingtalk_message_at)
        str_json = jsonpickle.encode(dingtalk_message)
```

I do not know why the result has some unexpect fields, this is the json result:

```
{
    "py/object": "dolphin.models.dingtalk_message.DingtalkMessage",
    "msgtype": "text",
    "text": {
        "py/object": "dolphin.models.dingtalk_message_text.DingtalkMessageText",
        "content": "test"
    },
    "at": {
        "py/object": "dolphin.models.dingtalk_message_at.DingtalkMessageAt",
        "isAtAll": true
    }
}
```

each layer has a field called `py/object` which was unexpect to get, why would this happen and how to remove it? what should I do to make json seriable clean? I tried this way:

```
jsonpickle.encode(my_object, make_refs=False)
```

but still not avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

`jsonpickle.encode(my_object, unpicklable=False)`